# two way binding textedit with viewmodel

Tags: android, android-fragments

How would I do a two way edit with bindings and a viewmodel ?

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.example.tutorme.viewmodel.ViewModel" />
</data>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/course_name_textfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="name"

        android:text="@={viewmodel.getname}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In my viewmodel I have

```
    private MutableLiveData<String> name;
public LiveData<String> getname() {
    return name;
}
```

I have the binding and viewmodel setup, however I keep getting the error that viewmodel.name.getValue() cannot be inverted there is no inverse methode.

How would I be able to fix this error ?

Comment: The issue here is `LiveData` don't work on 2 way binding. It must be `MutableLiveData<String>`. Databinding does not not auto cast `LiveData` to `MutableLiveData`.

Comment: k , this fixed the issue, however I also have a textedit for a number (double) and in the model: public MutableLiveData<Double> getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/price_textfield"
           
            android:text="@={viewmodel.getPrice}"
            android:hint="€/hr"

            android:inputType="numberDecimal"

and gives me error:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' how would I solve this ?

Comment: `EditText` always returns a text regardless if the `inputType` is number. But you can also create a `MediatorLiveData<Double>` that parses your `MutableLiveData<String>` every time it emits Strings (it can make your code a little bit ugly IMO!).